# Show $X^{-1}AX$ is an upper Hessenberg matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A \in \mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$, $x \in \mathbb{C}^n$, $X=[x,Ax,A^2x,\ldots,A^{n-1}x]$ and let $X$ be non-singular.

Show that $X^{-1}AX$ is an upper Hessenberg matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The matrix $X^{-1}AX$ is the matrix of the linear map given by $A$ but written w.r.t. the basis $(x,Ax,A^2x,\cdots,A^{n-1}x)$. So $X^{-1}AX$ is the so called companion matrix of the characteristic polynomial of $A$ see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix

From this you will clearly see that indeed $X^{-1}AX$ is a upper Hessenberg matrix.